# Como posso usar uma variável do less pra dar o endereço da fonte?

Tags: variáveis, less

No meu arquivo *less* tenho uma variável chamada **@address** com o endereço principal onde fica as fontes, eu tenho várias fontes e preciso por o diretório em todas com essa variável, porém não funciona.

**Uma das fontes do less**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Segoe UI"), local("Open Sans"), local("OpenSans"), url(@@address/ui/lib/fonts/opensans/v8/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mz8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
```

Em `url(@@address/ui/lib/.....)` eu preciso que seja o valor da variável! Como posso fazer isso, por quê não está dando certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`@{nome_da_variavel}`**](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation):

Por exemplo:

```less
@address: "/ui/lib/fonts/opensans/v8";

@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Segoe UI"),
       local("Open Sans"),
       local("OpenSans"),
       url("@{address}/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mz8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff") format('woff');
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou usar assim

Comment: Estava faltando um ponto e vírgula no final da declaração da variável :)